# Can Artifactory AQL return the actual artifact paths/names for module dependencies?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

We use Jenkins Maven builds that publish artifacts to Artifactory, along with their Build Info, and can use AQL to query a published artifact's dependencies.  Is it possible to specify AQL that will give us the actual artifact repo/path/name of the dependency?

Querying for "artifact.module.dependency" returns only the fields directly supported by "dependency" (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-EntitiesandFields).  Querying for "artifact.module.dependency.item" just parrots back the original artifact we asked about.

AQL:

```
items.find({
        "repo":{"$eq":"isone-app-staging"},
        "path":{"$match":"com/isone/sms/packages/package-batchjobs/40-dry-run-4"},
        "name":{"$match":"package-batchjobs-40-dry-run-4.pom"}
}).include("artifact.module.dependency")
```

Result:

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "isone-app-staging",
  "path" : "com/isone/sms/packages/package-batchjobs/40-dry-run-4",
  "name" : "package-batchjobs-40-dry-run-4.pom",
  "type" : "file",
...
  "artifacts" : [ {
    "modules" : [ {
      "dependencies" : [ {
        "dependency.md5" : "f62f14bcfe6923749141ad848a281c18",
        "dependency.name" : "com.isone.sms.server:ejb_FCMBatchBeans-api:40-dry-run-4",
        "dependency.scope" : "compile",
        "dependency.sha1" : "7ee63a9c50d5d57a2f31df52efe493d6b92b252f",
        "dependency.type" : "jar"
      }, {
...
```

What we're hoping to get with our query is an actual repo/path/name for the dependency, like 'isone-app-staging/com/isone/sms/server/ejb_FCMBatchBeans-api/40-dry-run-4/ejb_FCMBatchBeans-api-40-dry-run-4.jar'.

If we can't get this information directly from the search, we'll probably scrape the dependency.name and dependency.type and try to reconstruct it.  But it would be far more useful if we could just rely on Artifactory.